# Interpretation of $F(X)$ given that $X$ is a random variable and $F$ is the distribution function of $X$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

In my mathematical statistics lecture notes, there is a theorem which states:

$$\begin{equation}
P\{F(X) \leq F(x)\} = F(x) ,\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \tag{1}
\end{equation}$$

but it's not clear to me how I should interpret $F(X)$ here. If we consider that $F$ is defined as:

$$\begin{equation}
F(x)=P(X \leq x) \tag{2}
\end{equation}$$

then it appears to me that the only logical interpretation of $F(X)$ is:

$$\begin{equation}
F(X)=P(X \leq X)=1 \tag{3}
\end{equation}$$

but then the theorem statement would be equivalent to:

$$\begin{equation}
P\{F(X) \leq F(x)\} = P\{1 \leq F(x)\} = 0 \tag{*}
\end{equation}$$

which is absolutely useless. Might there be a sensible interpretation of $F(X)$ which I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $X$ a real random variable, i.e. $X:\Omega\to\Bbb R$. 
Then $F(X)=F\circ X=\omega\mapsto F(X(\omega))$, and for a fixed $x\in\Bbb R$, we have 
$$(F(X)\le F(x))\ =\ \{\omega:F(X(\omega))\le F(x)\} $$